# How to Recommend Deletion of certain Low Quality Posts

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I review questions and sometimes an answer has been automatically flagged for low quality.

Sometimes the answer is just short and the post still answers the question, but often it is giving correct information, but not nearly enough to be even close to answering the question.

I usually recommend deletion, because such posts attract downvotes and don't add anything to the question. But it's for none of the following reasons

- This is a commentary on another answer.
- This is a "I'm having this problem, too".
- This is spam.

Should we have a

- This post apparently misread or misinterpreted the question and does not answer the question.

*Update*.

Usually these posts have been deleted, so it's hard to find them, but here are a few recent examples:

- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/24188
  **Q** What's it called when furigana push characters apart because they're so long?
  **A** Its called ルビ but daily we call them 読み.
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23808
  **Q** What does "yoko" mean?
  **A** it means sunshine my mothers name is yoko and she is from japan
  (This answer has been converted to a comment.)
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23039/1628
  **Q** Is the Japanese word 体感温度 really a registered trademark ®?
  **A** ® means that the prefixed word has been registered and usage is constricted to the person or company under which it has been registered. The reason why this particular word was registered has been explained well by @Anon from another SE.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend deleting a *correct* answer that lacks information - I'd prefer it to be edited and improved. That said, I appreciate that the line has to be drawn somewhere; could you perhaps find an example of a particularly "basic" answer and link to/copy-paste it here?

Comment: @GoBusto See the update.